# How to adopt CancellationToken in compiled query in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 6.0 with .NET 7.0. In EF Core, `EF.CompileAsyncQuery` has many overloads with `CancellationToken` as a parameter.

For example this one:

```
public static Func<TContext, TParam1, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> CompileAsyncQuery<TContext, TParam1, TResult>(Expression<Func<TContext, TParam1, CancellationToken, TResult>> queryExpression) where TContext : DbContext
```

However, I cannot write async lambda expression here - if I try, I get an error:

> Error CS1989: Async lambda expressions cannot be converted to expression trees

How can I utilize this `CancellationToken` parameter?

At first, I tried to write async lambda expression in compiled queries - like this:

```cs
// This code will generate compiler error CS1989
public readonly Func<MyDbContext, SomeStatus, CancellationToken, Task<SomeTable?>> SomeQuery = EF.CompileAsyncQuery(
    async (MyDbContext dbContext, SomeStatus status, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await dbContext.SomeTable.Where(p => p.SomeStatus != status).OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken)
);
```

Then I got compiler error `CS1989`.

Later, tried to include a useless `CancellationToken` parameter inside my synchronized lambda expression. Like this:

```cs
// CancellationToken is not utilized here. It's just an unused argument.
public readonly Func<MyDbContext, SomeStatus, CancellationToken, Task<SomeTable?>> SomeQuery = EF.CompileAsyncQuery(
    (MyDbContext dbContext, SomeStatus status, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => dbContext.SomeTable.Where(p => p.SomeStatus != status).OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
);
```

This makes me confused. I think the `cancellationToken` argument is abandoned here. How do I adopt `CancellationToken` gracefully here?

In my opinion, the ideal situation shall be like this:

> Since async lambda expression is not allowed here, EF Core shall consume and utilize `CancellationToken` in it's generated statemachine.

When I invoke `SomeQuery`, I can pass `CancellationToken` as an argument and when I implement this query in lambda expression, I don't need to write a `CancellationToken` argument since I cannot consume it without async/await.

Then, somewhere between 'the invocation of `SomeQuery`' and 'my lambda expression implementation of `SomeQuery`', EF Core takes care of the `CancellationToken` and cancels DB operation for me if `CancellationToken` is cancelled.

Then, the code shall be something like this:

```cs
public readonly Func<MyDbContext, SomeStatus, CancellationToken, Task<SomeTable?>> SomeQuery = EF.CompileAsyncQuery(
    (MyDbContext dbContext, SomeStatus status) => dbContext.SomeTable.Where(p => p.SomeStatus != status).OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
);
```

Comment: Last queries are correct. Do not confuse that cancellation token is not used. EF Core will execute right command and pass your cancellation token.

Comment: Passing the CancellationToken isn't working, at least on SQL Server.  Issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29968

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks to your link. I followed your link and found out the correct source where CancellationToken is consumed. It is indeed consumed by EF Core. Here's the link: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2d70ae9af298bba9465e4b1d0f2692fda0cae6ec/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/CompiledQueryBase.cs#L76

Comment: Yep.  Not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *strange* and confusing API see this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14551) for details.

But basically the overloads that return IAsyncEnumerable work fine, but don't automatically use the passed-in cancellation token.  The overloads that return Task have weird undocumented limitations.  And since the Task-returning overloads are just convience methods, you can work around the limitations by always returning IAsyncEnumerable and processing it yourself if necessary.

And there's no need to pass the cancellation token if you return IAsyncEnumerable; you can use [IAsyncEnumerable.WithCancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.withcancellation?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAsyncEnumerableExtensions.WithCancellation%60%601)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) to cancel either the query execution or fetching the results.  You just have to wrap the compiled query in another function.  If you want to return a single entity, or a scalar, you can do that in the function too.

So something like this:

```cs
class Db: DbContext
{

    private static Func<Db, string, IAsyncEnumerable<Product>> GetProductByNameOrDefault_ = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((Db context, string name) =>
      context.Set<Product>().Where(p=>p.Name == name).OrderBy(p => p.Id).Take(1)
        );

    public async Task<Product> GetProductByNameOrDefault(string name, CancellationToken token)
    {
        await foreach( var p in GetProductByNameOrDefault_(this,name).WithCancellation(token) )
        {
            return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I have analysed EF Core Unite tests, they use syntax as in original question. There is no need to work with `IAsyncEnumerable` when single object returned.

Comment: Actually used, `.ExecuteAsync` returns `Func<TParam, CancellationToken, TEntity>`

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  I was misreading the code.  But it doesn't actually work; I'll create an issue.